# How to index, find, sort and download files from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to index all files on the s3 bucket, make some filtering, sorting, and pagination, and then have the possibility to download files.
There won't be a lot of files around 500.
Going to use AWS lambda and call s3 to get info about all files and then actually do all that stuff in memory.
Considering adding dynamoDB and adding a trigger when a new file is saved/removed from s3 but it looks like dynamoDb is also not so good in pagination and querying by fields except partition key. Perhaps it might work with querying with the sorting key but I need to find by parts of it.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Trying AWS lambda and processing in memory.

Comment: Do you need to filter/sort/paginate based on the title/metadata of the files, or based on the contents? Lambda does have a memory-limit, so you would have to be careful that downloading/processing all files doesn't hit the limit

Comment: 500 objects is not very much. The `list_objects()` call will return up to 1000 objects per call. You can then manipulate everything in memory. You don't really need to use a database unless you want to persist additional information for later use. Are you facing a specific problem at the moment?

Comment: @BertBlommers Yeah, I need to display the information based on the title and metadata.
I know then I cannot download files larger than 6 MB, so will use signed URLs.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Fair enough, I use listObjectsV2 and it also returns 1000 objects and then I can query more with the next token.
But then I need to sort them in memory, also if I need to filter by some title then I need to go over all 1000 in-memory objects and compare all.
Looking for a better solution.

Comment: The `list_objects()` API call will take maybe a second or so, but sorting and filtering them in memory will take milliseconds -- that's what computers do best! But you mention "metadata" -- where is this metadata being stored?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot download files larger than 6 MB"?

Comment: I use AWS lambda and it cannot download files large than 6mb from AWS s3.
listObjectsV2 returns some file metadata like size, lastModification date. And I need it too.